# Replace windows with Ubuntu with ISO burned onto disk?

Tags: cd

If I install Ubuntu using the installation cd will that replace my Windows 7 OS entirely?

Comment: Only if you choose the option to replace Windows. If you install alongside Windows, all will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

It depends according to the option you choose while installing Ubuntu.

- If you choose "Erase full disk and install Ubuntu option",it will completely format your HDD nd install Ubuntu on it.
- If you choose Install Ubuntu alongside windows option,the installer will erase all the partitions except your Windows `C` drive.
- If you choose "Something Else" option,you will be allowed to select the partition on which  Ubuntu is going to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to backup any files from Windows 7 before any type of installation of Ubuntu.